# Selenium getting the text out of the parent element excluding the child element's text

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm trying to get the text out of a parent element, excluding the text from childs element from a webpage that has a structure like this:

```
<div class="parent">
    "Apples"
    <span class="child">"Bananas"</span>
</div>
```

The text that is of interest to me is *"Apples"*. The Xpath selector `//*[@class='parent']/text()[last()]` works great in the browser, but I get an error saying `Message: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//*[@class='parent']/text()[last()]" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.`, when I try to obtain it with Selenium in Python like this:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ("//*[@class='parent']/text()[last()]")).text()
```

To sum it up my goal is to get the string *"Apples"* returned to me, as of now I was only successful in getting a string like *"ApplesBananas"*. The string itself is not predictable so filtering based on `contains()` is out of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can not be done with direct XPath locator only.
What you need to do here is:
Get the parent element text (it will include parent element text content and child element text contents).
Then remove child element text contents, as following:

```py
all_text = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ("//*[@class='parent']")).text
child_text = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ("//*[@class='parent']//*")).text

parent_text = all_text.replace(child_text, '')
```

In case there are multiple child nodes replacing the child text content should be done for all those nodes, as following:

```py
parent_text = ""
all_text = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ("//*[@class='parent']")).text
child_elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, ("//*[@class='parent']//*"))
for child_element in child_elements:
    parent_text = all_text.replace(child_element.text, '')
print(parent_text)
```